# Dynamic Regex for Decimal Precision not Working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following hard-coded RegEx expression for decimal precision & scale, which works (in another project):

```
// This would be a Decimal(2,3)
var regex = /\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$/;
var result = regex.test(text);
```

However, I don't want to hard-code multiple variations.  And, interestingly, the following fails...but I don't know why.

I "think" the concatenation may (somehow) be effecting the "test"

- What am I doing wrong here?

SAMPLE:

```
var validationRules = {
    decimal: {
        hasPrecision: function (precision, scale, text) {

            var regex = new RegExp('\d{0,' + precision + '}(\.\d{1,' + scale + '})?$'); 
            var result = regex.test(text);

            // result is ALWAYS true ????
            alert(result);
            alert(regex);
        }
    }
};
```

FAILING SAMPLE-SNIPPET:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            var validationRules = {
                decimal: {
                    hasPrecision: function (precision, scale, text) {
                        
                        var regex = new RegExp('\d{0,' + precision + '}(\.\d{1,' + scale + '})?$'); 
                        var result = regex.test(text);

                        alert(result);
                        alert(regex);
                    }
                }
            };

            var masks = {
                decimal: function (e) {

                    // TODO: get Kendo MaskedTextBox to run RegEx
                    var regex = new RegExp("^([0-9\.])$");
                    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);

                    if (!regex.test(key)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };

            var button = $('.btn');
            var textbox = $('.txt');

            textbox.on('keypress', masks.decimal);
            button.on('click', function () {
                var text = textbox.val();

                validationRules.decimal.hasPrecision(2, 3, text);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1111" class="txt">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Run it">
```

Comment: You should double escape inside RegExp: `\\d`. It's of type string.

Comment: @revo Nope...didnt work.  But thank you.

Comment: After correcting that issue I think you should consider using `^` anchor  or at least `\b` as well to avoid values like `123.123` be permitted while invoking `.hasPrecision(2, 3, text)`

Comment: Try `new RegExp('^\\d{0,' + precision + '}(\\.\\d{1,' + scale + '})?$');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* look at the result when building dynamic strings. In your case you're building it and just assuming it's turning into the REGEX pattern you want.

What you're actually building is, for example:

```
d{0,2}(.d{1,3})?$
```

Why? Because REGEX patterns built via the constructor (as opposed to literals) are built as strings - and in strings `\` is interpreted as an escape character.

You, however, need these back slashes to persist into your pattern, so you need to double escape. In effect, you need to escape the escape so the final one is retained.

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\d{0,' + precision + '}(\\.\\d{1,' + scale + '})?$');
```

This will result in an equivalent of your hard-coded pattern *assuming* `precision` and `scale` contain the intergers you think they do. Check this too. (If they contain floats, for example, this will ruin your pattern.)

As for your false positives, this is probably down to a missing start-anchor instruction, i.e. `^`.

```
/\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$/.test("1234"); //true
/^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$/.test("1234"); //false, note ^
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this I have implement on my project and it's working fine

const integer = Number(4)

const decimal=Number(2)

const reg = new RegExp(`^[0-9]{0,${integer }}(\\.\\d[0-9]{0,${decimal- 1}})?$`)

return value && !reg.test(value) ? `Maximum length for integer is ${integer} and for decimal is ${decimal}` : undefined;